# Same xmlns multiple times inside the same element

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I'm struggling to find an example like the following:

```
<myElement>
   <child xmlns="sameNamespace" color="blue"/>
   <child xmlns="sameNamespace" color="red"/>
</myElement>
```

Can the exact same xmlns appear more than once in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, different (or the same) default namespaces can be declared on different elements.

In your posted example, both `child` elements are in the `sameNamespace` namespace, and `myElement` is in no namespace.

Comment: What do you mean with"different default namespaces"? I would be happy if you said "same default namespaces" or something like that :)

Comment: So, you're right that they're the same default namespaces.  I updated the answer to clarify that they can also be the same.   (By mentioning "different" I'd meant to call attention to the possibility of independent control of the namespaces on separate elements -- doesn't, for example, have to be the same namespace everywhere in an XML document.)